# fetch aws credentials from assumed role with web identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-iam

I am trying to fetch credentials to be used for spark submit. I already have an assumed role with web identity provider that airflow task is doing for me. But in order to export these credentials to spark, I need to fetch these credentials and set it in Spark context. how can I do it?

```
[2022-08-23, 11:07:42 UTC] {{subprocess.py:89}} INFO - + aws configure list
[2022-08-23, 11:07:43 UTC] {{subprocess.py:89}} INFO -       Name                    Value             Type    Location
[2022-08-23, 11:07:43 UTC] {{subprocess.py:89}} INFO -       ----                    -----             ----    --------
[2022-08-23, 11:07:43 UTC] {{subprocess.py:89}} INFO -    profile                <not set>             None    None
[2022-08-23, 11:07:43 UTC] {{subprocess.py:89}} INFO - access_key     ****************WWSO assume-role-with-web-identity
[2022-08-23, 11:07:43 UTC] {{subprocess.py:89}} INFO - secret_key     ****************wZz0 assume-role-with-web-identity
```

As you can see above, the access keys are not stored in environment variables. However a web identity access token is present and the authentication to AWS is happening through it

Answer (score 0):

Once you got the environment variable of access key and secret key, you can set it by

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", AWS_ACCESS_KEY)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", AWS_SECRET_KEY)
```

Comment: Thanks. But the credentials are not stored in environment variables. The question is about how to fetch those credentials. Not how to use the credentials